# What does the boolean in the follwong controller do?

Tags: java, controller, boolean, scenebuilder

I'm doing a beginner's course on Java fx and I have the task of creating a simple pocket calculator with the Scene Builder based on the MVC pattern. I understand model and view, but I don't understand the purpose of the boolean isTypingNumber in the following controller.
My teacher says this should be used to check whether the user is typing in a number so that he cannot perform any other operations during this time, but I do not understand what he means by that or what that is supposed to mean in this context. Maybe someone can give me an explanation here.

Best Regards~

Controller:

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Controller {
        
        @FXML
        Text resultLabel;
        boolean isTypingNumber = false; 
        double firstNumber = 0;
        double secondNumber = 0;
        String operation = "";
        Model model = new Model();
        
        public void numberTapped(ActionEvent event) { //When user tapps on a number
            String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText(); 
            
            if (isTypingNumber) { 
                resultLabel.setText(resultLabel.getText() + value);
            } else {
                resultLabel.setText(value);
                isTypingNumber = true;
            }
            
        }
        
        public void calculationTapped(ActionEvent event) { //When User clicks a + / -  / * or /
            isTypingNumber = false;
            firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(resultLabel.getText());
            operation = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
            
        }
        
        public void equalsTapped(ActionEvent event) { // When click on =
            isTypingNumber = false;
            secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(resultLabel.getText());
            double result = model.calculate(firstNumber, secondNumber, operation);
            resultLabel.setText(String.valueOf(result));
            
        }
        
        public void restartTapped(ActionEvent event ){ //When click on "C"
            resultLabel.setText("0");
            firstNumber = 0;
            secondNumber = 0;
            
        }
}
```

And here the Model maybe for better understanding:

```
package application;

public class Model {
    
    public double calculate(double number1, double number2, String operation) {
    
        switch (operation) {
        case "+":
            return number1 + number2;
        case "-":
            return number1 - number2;
        case "*":
            return number1 * number2;
        case "/":
            if(number2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Durch 0 teilen geht nicht");
            }
            
            else {
                return number1/number2;
            }
            
            
            
        
        }
        
        return 0;
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean `isTypingNumber` is used to decide whether a number that the user entered should be appended to the text in `resultLabel` or replace the text in `resultLabel`.

Let's say the user wants to calculate "22 + 33":

1. the user presses "2". `isTypingNumber` is false, so the text in `resultLabel` will be replaced with "2" and `isTypingNumber` is set to true
2. the user presses "2" again. `isTypingNumber` is true, so the number is appended to the text in `resultLabel` which now contains "22".
3. the user presses "+". This is stored in `operation`, `firstNumber` is changed to 22 and `isTypingNumber` is set to false
4. the user presses "3". Should the text in `resultLabel` be changed to "223" by appending the "3" or should it be changed to "3" by replacing the contents? `isTypingNumber` answers this question: it is false, so the text in `resultLabel` will be replaced with "3".

It is in that step number 4 where the need for `isTypingNumber` becomes obvious.

You could possibly remove `isTypingNumber` if you changed the text in `resultLabel` to an empty string in step 3, but IMHO that would make the user interface awkward: as soon as you press an operation button the number that you entered previously would disappear. And it would mean that if the user would try to do several calculations ("22 + 33 =", "3 * 15 =") he would need to press  the restart button in between.